# How to best write out a std::vector < std::string > container to a HDF5 dataset?

Tags: c++, stl, hdf5

Given a vector of strings, what is the best way to write them out to a HDF5 dataset?  At the moment I'm doing something like the following:

```
  const unsigned int MaxStrLength = 512;

  struct TempContainer {
    char string[MaxStrLength];
  };

  void writeVector (hid_t group, std::vector<std::string> const & v)
  {
    //
    // Firstly copy the contents of the vector into a temporary container
    std::vector<TempContainer> tc;
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = v.begin ()
                                              , end = v.end ()
      ; i != end
      ; ++i)
    {
      TempContainer t;
      strncpy (t.string, i->c_str (), MaxStrLength);
      tc.push_back (t);
    }


    //
    // Write the temporary container to a dataset
    hsize_t     dims[] = { tc.size () } ;
    hid_t dataspace = H5Screate_simple(sizeof(dims)/sizeof(*dims)
                               , dims
                               , NULL);

    hid_t strtype = H5Tcopy (H5T_C_S1);
    H5Tset_size (strtype, MaxStrLength);

    hid_t datatype = H5Tcreate (H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof (TempConainer));
    H5Tinsert (datatype
      , "string"
      , HOFFSET(TempContainer, string)
      , strtype);

    hid_t dataset = H5Dcreate1 (group
                          , "files"
                          , datatype
                          , dataspace
                          , H5P_DEFAULT);

    H5Dwrite (dataset, datatype, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, &tc[0] );

    H5Dclose (dataset);
    H5Sclose (dataspace);
    H5Tclose (strtype);
    H5Tclose (datatype);
}
```

At a minimum, I would really like to change the above so that:

1. It uses variable length strings
2. I don't need to have a temporary container

I have no restrictions over how I store the data so for example, it doesn't have to be a *COMPOUND* datatype if there is a better way to do this.

**EDIT:**  Just to narrow the problem down, I'm relatively familiar with playing with the data on the C++ side, it's the HDF5 side where I need most of the help.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Many thanks to [dirkgently](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66692/dirkgently) for his help in answering this.]

To write a variable length string in HDF5 use the following:

```
// Create the datatype as follows
hid_t datatype = H5Tcopy (H5T_C_S1);
H5Tset_size (datatype, H5T_VARIABLE);

// 
// Pass the string to be written to H5Dwrite
// using the address of the pointer!
const char * s = v.c_str ();
H5Dwrite (dataset
  , datatype
  , H5S_ALL
  , H5S_ALL
  , H5P_DEFAULT
  , &s );
```

One solution for writing a container is to write each element individually.  This can be achieved using [hyperslabs](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/select.html).

For example:

```
class WriteString
{
public:
  WriteString (hid_t dataset, hid_t datatype
      , hid_t dataspace, hid_t memspace)
    : m_dataset (dataset), m_datatype (datatype)
    , m_dataspace (dataspace), m_memspace (memspace)
    , m_pos () {}

private:
  hid_t m_dataset;
  hid_t m_datatype;
  hid_t m_dataspace;
  hid_t m_memspace;
  int m_pos;
```

//...

```
public:
  void operator ()(std::vector<std::string>::value_type const & v)
  {
    // Select the file position, 1 record at position 'pos'
    hsize_t count[] = { 1 } ;
    hsize_t offset[] = { m_pos++ } ;
    H5Sselect_hyperslab( m_dataspace
      , H5S_SELECT_SET
      , offset
      , NULL
      , count
      , NULL );

    const char * s = v.c_str ();
    H5Dwrite (m_dataset
      , m_datatype
      , m_memspace
      , m_dataspace
      , H5P_DEFAULT
      , &s );
    }    
};
```

// ...

```
void writeVector (hid_t group, std::vector<std::string> const & v)
{
  hsize_t     dims[] = { m_files.size ()  } ;
  hid_t dataspace = H5Screate_simple(sizeof(dims)/sizeof(*dims)
                                    , dims, NULL);

  dims[0] = 1;
  hid_t memspace = H5Screate_simple(sizeof(dims)/sizeof(*dims)
                                    , dims, NULL);

  hid_t datatype = H5Tcopy (H5T_C_S1);
  H5Tset_size (datatype, H5T_VARIABLE);

  hid_t dataset = H5Dcreate1 (group, "files", datatype
                             , dataspace, H5P_DEFAULT);

  // 
  // Select the "memory" to be written out - just 1 record.
  hsize_t offset[] = { 0 } ;
  hsize_t count[] = { 1 } ;
  H5Sselect_hyperslab( memspace, H5S_SELECT_SET, offset
                     , NULL, count, NULL );

  std::for_each (v.begin ()
      , v.end ()
      , WriteStrings (dataset, datatype, dataspace, memspace));

  H5Dclose (dataset);
  H5Sclose (dataspace);
  H5Sclose (memspace);
  H5Tclose (datatype);
}
```

Comment: You know what? HDF5 is one of those things I've always wanted to read and write. But procrastination being my middle name that hasn't materialized. Thanks to you I've decided to give it a more dedicated shot this time. I'd be very, very interested to know, where you are using this, if possible.

Comment: We are looking to change how our static analysis tool stores the data that it gathers from its analysis.  The data will contain tree like structures (scopes, types etc) and lists of diagnostics.  At this stage I'm just evaluating how well HDF5 handles the different types of data.

Comment: This question (that I asked) outlines the kind of features that we are evaluating for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547195/evaluating-hdf5-what-limitations-features-does-hdf5-provide-for-modelling-data

Answer (score 5):

Here is some working code for writing a vector of variable length strings using the HDF5 c++ API.

I incorporate some of the suggestions in the other posts:

1. use H5T_C_S1 and H5T_VARIABLE
2. use `string::c_str()` to obtain pointers to the strings
3. place the pointers into a `vector` of `char*` and pass to the HDF5 API

It is **not necessary** to create expensive copies of the string (e.g. with `strdup()`). `c_str()` returns a pointer to the null terminated data of the underlying string. This is precisely what the function is intended for. Of course, strings with embedded nulls will not work with this...

`std::vector` is guaranteed to have contiguous underlying storage, so using `vector` and `vector::data()` is the same as using raw arrays but is of course much neater and safer than the clunky, old-fashioned c way of doing things.

```
#include "H5Cpp.h"
void write_hdf5(H5::H5File file, const std::string& data_set_name,
                const std::vector<std::string>& strings )
{
    H5::Exception::dontPrint();

    try
    {
        // HDF5 only understands vector of char* :-(
        std::vector<const char*> arr_c_str;
        for (unsigned ii = 0; ii < strings.size(); ++ii) 
            arr_c_str.push_back(strings[ii].c_str());

        //
        //  one dimension
        // 
        hsize_t     str_dimsf[1] {arr_c_str.size()};
        H5::DataSpace   dataspace(1, str_dimsf);

        // Variable length string
        H5::StrType datatype(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE); 
        H5::DataSet str_dataset = file.createDataSet(data_set_name, datatype, dataspace);

        str_dataset.write(arr_c_str.data(), datatype);
    }
    catch (H5::Exception& err)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(string("HDF5 Error in " ) 
                                    + err.getFuncName()
                                    + ": "
                                    + err.getDetailMsg());


    }
}
```

Comment: nice! But how do you read that from file back into a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: What OS does this work on? Because it looks like this will cause segfaults on a lot of machines, or just corrupt your data. I'm suspicious because I did something similar which worked on Linux but failed on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at cleaner code: I suggest you create a functor that'll take a string and save it to the HDF5 Container (in a desired mode). Richard, I used the wrong algorithm, please re-check!

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), write_hdf5);

struct hdf5 : public std::unary_function<std::string, void> {
    hdf5() : _dataset(...) {} // initialize the HDF5 db
    ~hdf5() : _dataset(...) {} // close the the HDF5 db
    void operator(std::string& s) {
            // append 
            // use s.c_str() ?
    }
};
```

Does that help get started?

Comment: Well - yes I'm hoping to be able reach this kind of style - however, I wasn't sure if it was (a) possible and (b) efficient.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm really very new to HDF5, so I have no idea what needs to be written where you have "// append".

Comment: I've only so much heard of HDF5. I meant by append whatever you are doing under the comment // Write the temporary container to a dataset.

Comment: And this the crux of the problem.  The "H5Dwrite" method takes a 'void*' argument and writes that, it's a bit like "memcpy" or "memmove" where you give it a size and a block of data.  At least that's what I currently think! :)

Comment: So use your_data_string.c_str() and your_data_string.size(). void* is really a way of letting any kind of data pass-through. I wonder why you need the struct TempContainer though.

Comment: Ok.  The key question is:  What are the parameters to H5Dwrite so that it will only append a single string into the next slot of the dataset?  Then, as you say I can use a .c_str method.  But currently I am having to first create a C style container with my strings which is dumped in one go.

Comment: What I am suggesting is, instead of creating a single huge string and a single HDFwrite() call, can't you do the opposite i.e. write many strings using multiple HDFwrite() calls?

Comment: So we're asking the same question now!  ;)  All of the examples for H5Dwrite that I've found appear to write the entire "dataset" in one go, not entry by entry.

Comment: From what I can see here -- http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-Write -- this approach should work.

Comment: 'HDFwrite() writes a partial dataset at a time.'

Comment: Thanks for helping with this.  One of the issues is that I do not know how to write a partial dataset yet, nor have I been able to find examples that use anything other than H5S_ALL for the dataspce.    Re: HDFwrite, it appears to be matlab specific?  At least it is not in the HDF5 library I have.

Comment: No its there in the C library as well. Have you seen this already: http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Intro/IntroExamples.html#CheckAndReadExample ?

Comment: I hadn't seen this - I'll try it out.  Thanks for this.

Comment: Also this: Reading and Writing a portion of a dataset somewhere nearly halfway through this page http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.intro.html#Intro-WhatIs.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, with the caveat that I wanted a vector of strings stored as an *attribute*. The tricky thing with attributes is that we can't use fancy dataspace features like hyperslabs (at least with the C++ API).

But in either case, it may be useful to enter a vector of strings into a single entry in a dataset (if, for example, you always expect to read them together). In this case all the magic comes with the *type*, not with the dataspace itself.

There are basically 4 steps:

1. Make a `vector<const char*>` which points to the strings.
2. Create a `hvl_t` structure that points to the vector and contains it's length.
3. Create the datatype. This is a `H5::VarLenType` wrapping a (variable length) `H5::StrType`.
4. Write the `hvl_t` type to a dataset.

The really nice part of this method is that you're stuffing the whole entry into what HDF5 considers a scalar value. This means that making it an attribute (rather than a dataset) is trivial.

Whether you choose this solution or the one with each string in its own dataset entry is probably also a matter of the desired performance: if you're looking for random access to specific strings, it's probably better to write the strings out in a dataset so they can be indexed. If you're always going to read them all out together this solution may work just as well.

Here's a short example of how to do this, using the C++ API and a simple scalar dataset:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Part 0: make up some data
  std::vector<std::string> strings;
  for (int iii = 0; iii < 10; iii++) {
    strings.push_back("this is " + std::to_string(iii));
  }

  // Part 1: grab pointers to the chars
  std::vector<const char*> chars;
  for (const auto& str: strings) {
    chars.push_back(str.data());
  }

  // Part 2: create the variable length type
  hvl_t hdf_buffer;
  hdf_buffer.p = chars.data();
  hdf_buffer.len = chars.size();

  // Part 3: create the type
  auto s_type = H5::StrType(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE);
  s_type.setCset(H5T_CSET_UTF8); // just for fun, you don't need this
  auto svec_type = H5::VarLenType(&s_type);

  // Part 4: write the output to a scalar dataset
  H5::H5File out_file("vtest.h5", H5F_ACC_EXCL);
  H5::DataSet dataset(
    out_file.createDataSet("the_ds", svec_type, H5S_SCALAR));
  dataset.write(&hdf_buffer, svec_type);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party but I've modified Leo Goodstadt's answer based on the comments regarding segfaults. I am on linux, but I don't have such problems. I wrote 2 functions, one to write a vector of std::string to a dataset of a given name in an open H5File, and another to read back the resulting data sets into a vector of std::string. Note there may unnecessary copying between types a few times that can be more optimised. Here is working code for writing and reading:

```
void write_varnames( const std::string& dsetname, const std::vector<std::string>& strings, H5::H5File& f)
  {
    H5::Exception::dontPrint();

    try
      {
        // HDF5 only understands vector of char* :-(
        std::vector<const char*> arr_c_str;
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < strings.size(); ++ii)
      {
        arr_c_str.push_back(strings[ii].c_str());
      }

        //
        //  one dimension
        // 
        hsize_t     str_dimsf[1] {arr_c_str.size()};
        H5::DataSpace   dataspace(1, str_dimsf);

        // Variable length string
        H5::StrType datatype(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE); 
        H5::DataSet str_dataset = f.createDataSet(dsetname, datatype, dataspace);

        str_dataset.write(arr_c_str.data(), datatype);
      }
    catch (H5::Exception& err)
      {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("HDF5 Error in ")  
                 + err.getFuncName()
                 + ": "
                 + err.getDetailMsg());


      }
  }
```

And to read:

```
std::vector<std::string> read_string_dset( const std::string& dsname, H5::H5File& f )
  {
    H5::DataSet cdataset = f.openDataSet( dsname );


    H5::DataSpace space = cdataset.getSpace();

    int rank = space.getSimpleExtentNdims();

    hsize_t dims_out[1];

    int ndims = space.getSimpleExtentDims( dims_out, NULL);

    size_t length = dims_out[0];

    std::vector<const char*> tmpvect( length, NULL );

    fprintf(stdout, "In read STRING dataset, got number of strings: [%ld]\n", length );

    std::vector<std::string> strs(length);
    H5::StrType datatype(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE); 
    cdataset.read( tmpvect.data(), datatype);

    for(size_t x=0; x<tmpvect.size(); ++x)
      {
        fprintf(stdout, "GOT STRING [%s]\n", tmpvect[x] );
        strs[x] = tmpvect[x];
      }

    return strs;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know,hdf5 file only accept data with the format as char*, which is
an address.So the most natural way is like dynamically creating consecutive address (the space size is given), and copying the value of vector into it.

```
char* strs = NULL;
strs = (char*)malloc(date.size() * (date[0].size() + 1) * (char)sizeof(char));

for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++) {
    string s = date[i];
    strcpy(strs + i * (date[0].size() + 1), date[i].c_str());
}
```

The complete code is shown as below,

```
 bool writeString(hid_t file_id, vector<string>& date, string dateSetName) {
    hid_t dataset_id, dataspace_id;  /* identifiers */
    herr_t status;
    hid_t dtype;
    size_t size;
    hsize_t dims[1] = { date.size() };
    dataspace_id = H5Screate_simple(1, dims, NULL);


    dtype = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
    size = (date[0].size() + 1) * sizeof(char);
    status = H5Tset_size(dtype, size);

    char* strs = NULL;
    strs = (char*)malloc(date.size() * (date[0].size() + 1) * (char)sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++) {
        string s = date[i];
        strcpy(strs + i * (date[0].size() + 1), date[i].c_str());
        
    }

    dataset_id = H5Dcreate(file_id, dateSetName.c_str(), dtype, dataspace_id, H5P_DEFAULT,
        H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

    status = H5Dwrite(dataset_id, dtype, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, strs);

    status = H5Dclose(dataset_id);
    status = H5Sclose(dataspace_id);
    status = H5Tclose(dtype);
    free(strs);
    return true;
}
```

**Don't forget to free the pointer.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a TempContainer, you can use a simple std::vector (you could also templatized it to match T -> basic_string .
Something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class StringToVector
  : std::unary_function<std::vector<char>, std::string> {
public:
  std::vector<char> operator()(const std::string &s) const {
    // assumes you want a NUL-terminated string
    const char* str = s.c_str();
    std::size_t size = 1 + std::strlen(str);
    // s.size() != strlen(s.c_str())
    std::vector<char> buf(&str[0], &str[size]);
    return buf;
  }
};

void conv(const std::vector<std::string> &vi,
          std::vector<std::vector<char> > &vo)
{
  // assert vo.size() == vi.size()
  std::transform(vi.begin(), vi.end(),
                 vo.begin(),
                 StringToVector());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of having the ability to *read* `std::vector<std::string>` I'm posting my solution, based on the hints from Leo here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15220532/364818.

I've mixed C and C++ APIs. Please feel free to edit this and make it simpler.

Note that the HDF5 API returns a list of `char*`pointers when you call read. These `char*` pointers must be freed after use, otherwise there is a memory leak.

Usage example

```
H5::Attribute Foo = file.openAttribute("Foo");
std::vector<std::string> foos
Foo >> foos;
```

Here's the code

```
  const H5::Attribute& operator>>(const H5::Attribute& attr0, std::vector<std::string>& array)
  {
      H5::Exception::dontPrint();

      try
      {
          hid_t attr = attr0.getId();

          hid_t atype = H5Aget_type(attr);
          hid_t aspace = H5Aget_space(attr);
          int rank = H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims(aspace);
          if (rank != 1) throw PBException("Attribute " + attr0.getName() + " is not a string array");

          hsize_t sdim[1];
          herr_t ret = H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(aspace, sdim, NULL);
          size_t size = H5Tget_size (atype);
          if (size != sizeof(void*))
          {
              throw PBException("Internal inconsistency. Expected pointer size element");
          }

          // HDF5 only understands vector of char* :-(
          std::vector<char*> arr_c_str(sdim[0]);

          H5::StrType stringType(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE);
          attr0.read(stringType, arr_c_str.data());
          array.resize(sdim[0]);
          for(int i=0;i<sdim[0];i++)
          {
              // std::cout << i << "=" << arr_c_str[i] << std::endl;
              array[i] = arr_c_str[i];
              free(arr_c_str[i]);
          }

      }
      catch (H5::Exception& err)
      {
          throw std::runtime_error(string("HDF5 Error in " )
                                    + err.getFuncName()
                                    + ": "
                                    + err.getDetailMsg());


      }

      return attr0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about HDF5, but you can use

```
struct TempContainer {
    char* string;
};
```

and then copy the strings this way:

```
TempContainer t;
t.string = strdup(i->c_str());
tc.push_back (t);
```

This will allocate a string with the exact size, and also improves a lot when inserting or reading from the container (in your example there's an array copied, in this case only a pointer). You can also use std::vector:

```
std::vector<char *> tc;
...
tc.push_back(strdup(i->c_str());
```

Comment: Sure.  Ideally I wouldn't need the temporary container at all.  This code adds the slight disadvantage that the memory needs to be freed explicitly.